# Paypal integration to Flask application

Tags: javascript, paypal, flask

I am slightly misunderstand Paypal flow event after reading https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/. I'd like to integrate express checkout and credit card payments to my site. I am using `Flask` and `paypalrestsdk` without any Flask extensions.

Here is excerpts from my app:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    # Page with but form, price/quantity/name values
    # are stored in hidden fields, "Buy now" acts as submit
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/payment/paypal', methods=['POST'])
def payment_paypal():
    # Here I am creating dict with required params
    payment_template = {
        'intent': 'sale',
        'payer': {'payment_method': 'paypal'},
        'redirect_urls': {
          'return_url': url_for('payment_paypal_execute'),
          'cancel_url': url_for('payment_paypal_error')
        },
        ......
    }

    payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment(payment)

    if payment.create():
        print('Payment "{}" created successfully'.format(payment.id))

        for link in payment.links:
            if link.method == "REDIRECT":
                redirect_url = str(link.href)
                print('Redirect for approval: {}'.format(redirect_url))
                return redirect(redirect_urls)

@app.route('/payment/paypal/execute', methods=['GET'])
def payment_paypal_execute():
    payer_id = request.args.get('payerId')
    payment_id = request.args.get('paymentId')
    token = request.args.get('token')

    pending_payment = PayPalPayment.query.filter_by(token=token).filter_by(state='created').first_or_404()

    try:
        payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(pending_payment.payment_id)
    except paypalrestsdk.exceptions.ResourceNotFound as ex:
        print('Paypal resource not found: {}'.format(ex))
        abort(404)

    if payment.execute({"payer_id": payer_id}):
        pending_payment.state = payment.state
        pending_payment.updated_at = datetime.strptime(payment.update_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('payment/success.html', payment_id=payment.id, state=payment.state)

    return render_template('payment/error.html', payment_error=payment.error, step='Finallizing payment')
```

It is works fine, after clicking on button `payment`  created succesfully (with state `created`) user redirected to approval page. There he click "Confirm"... And I never returned to my application, event when I specifying return_url! I.e. application could never be informed that buyer approved payment and it should be updated in my own database and new license should be sent to that person.

Problems:

1. I cannot find way to define some callback using `pyhtonrestsdk`. How to do it?
2. Even if I adding callback (I tried embed Express Checkout using pure Javascript button code) with `data-callback` my application was not called. I suspect because remote server could not call `http://127.0.0.1/payment/paypal/success`
3. User could close window with PayPal confirmation immediately after click "Confirm" so I could not trust browser redirection it it performed somehow later.

Finally, I suspect that I do not understand PayPal workflow clear, but I could not find more information about it event on developers portal.

Comment: I'm getting some weird CORS error when I try to redirect. "Unable to load paypal.sandbox.com no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, devil hides in details. My main issue was following: paypal does not redirects me to my application, but I found that it redirects me (after confirmation) to URL which looks like `https://sandbox.paypal.com/` with query string contains desired parameters. I.e. `redirect_urls` works as expected, just redirects me to wrong host.

After that I remembered that `url_for` generate **relative** links. So just added keyword `_external=True` I've been redirected to my application with all required arguments and payment successfully confirmed and executed.

I.e. correct `redirect_urls` block will looks  like:

```
'redirect_urls': {
    'return_url': url_for('payment_paypal_execute', _external=True),
    'cancel_url': url_for('payment_paypal_error', _external=True)
}
```

Finally I've got following workflow:

1. Opened `/` (`index`) which has button `Pay with PayPal` It is image button inside form. Beside this button form contains hidden fields with amount, product name and quantity (actually if is not good idea because we cannot trust to user, so I storing only `product_license_type_id` which stored in DB and contains all required information about product).
2. Once clicked it `POST` form to '/payment/paypal' (paypal_create) where create object `Payment` with filling all fields. If call `payment.create` finished successfully it also creates record in my own database with `payment_id` and `state` (these fields related to paypal workflow, of course actually I am storing couple of other fields related to my app).
3. Once payment created on PayPal side, application look into response for list `payment.links`. We  want one with `rel == 'approval_url'` and `method == 'REDIRECT'` and return `flask.redirect(found_link)`
4. On PayPal site buyer should click 'Approve', review shipping address and after that he will be immediately redirected to `redirect_urls.return_url` with following parameters in query string: `PayerID`, `paymentId`, `token`.
5. Once redirected back you should get this parameters from query string (keep in mind - it is case-sensitive!), find payment using PayPal API (`payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(payment_id)`) and finalize it (`payment.execute({"payer_id": payer_id}):`).
6. When finalized payment changes status to `approved`.
7. ....
8. PROFIT!

**UPD**: You do not need to turn on "AutoRedirect" in you selling account preferences and this approach suitable for integrating one account into multiple sites.

Comment: Sorry for second comment, but on step 3 when I try to redirect I get "Unable to load paypal.sandbox.com no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.  I am running flask locally. Did this occur for you?